# Inequality involving max of two numbers

Tags: inequality

For $\frac 12 < \beta < 1, 0<\gamma<\frac 12,$ and $0<\alpha<1,$ is it true that

$$\alpha\beta + (1-\alpha)(1-\gamma) \leq \frac{\max\{\alpha\beta + (1-\alpha)\gamma, \alpha(1-\beta) +(1-\alpha)(1-\gamma)\}}{\max\{\alpha,1-\alpha\}}~?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not true. There are infinitely many counterexamples $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ such that
$$\frac 45\lt \alpha\lt 1,\quad\beta=\frac 35,\quad\gamma=\frac 18.$$